# How to get DOM reference of Ant design components in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd, use-ref, ant-design-pro

I am using Ant design components. I need to get 'ref' of `Image` component, but it doesn't support 'ref' property.

I am trying to do this.

```
const ImageRef = useRef(null)

<Image ref={ImageRef} />
```

Is there any alternate way?

Comment: Can you give some more details/code like, what are doing with that Image etc..? Thank you

Comment: @Ved I am trying to get image offsetHeight and offsetWidth / naturalHeight and naturalWidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code, by wrapping the `<Image/>` component inside `<span>`

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Image } from "antd";

const App = () => {
  const ImageRef = useRef(null);

  const display = () => {
    console.log(ImageRef.current.children[0].children[0].naturalHeight);
    console.log(ImageRef.current.children[0].children[0].naturalWidth);
  };
  return (
    <span ref={ImageRef}>
      <Image
        onClick={display}
        width={200}
        src="https://gw.alipayobjects.com/zos/antfincdn/aPkFc8Sj7n/method-draw-image.svg"
      />
    </span>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Note:**

```
console.log(ImageRef.current);
```

gives

[image: screenshot]

So if you want image offsetHeight and offsetWidth / naturalHeight and naturalWidth you need to do the following

```
console.log(ImageRef.current.children[0].children[0].naturalHeight);
```

I hope this helps you!